# Redshift SQL is there a way to only sum numeric entries from a column that has a mixture of numbers and text strings

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a column `my_column` that has a mixture of numbers and strings

```
1,
2,
hi,
4,
hello
```

is there a way to only sum the numeric values of this column in redshift sql?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to

https://blog.fishtownanalytics.com/how-to-safely-convert-strings-to-integers-in-redshift-a4d7aa39c70

The following should work:

```
SELECT SUM(
    case
      when trim(my_column) ~ '^[0-9]+$' then trim(my_column)
      else null 
    end::int
  ) sum_ints
FROM
  my_table
```

Comment: thank you! this has been a huge help and i learned something about REGEX thanks to your advice

Answer (score 0):

Off topic, but if you have mixed content in a column then it’s likely your data model and physical implementation need some work.

If you are paying for cpu you should in my view invest at least some effort in reducing the number of cycles expended “working around” a potentially poor physical data model.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just a small note that some people would pick on this as technically being more suitably posted as a comment on the question than an answer..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do negative numbers and decimals

```
SUM(
    case
      when regexp_replace(my_column,'([^-0-9.])','') ~ '^[-]{0,}[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+){0,}$|^[-]{0,}([0-9]+){0,}\\.[0-9]+$' then regexp_replace(my_column,'([^-0-9.])','')
      else null 
    end::float
) as sum_my_column,
```

It's super aggressive and will pull out numbers from anything that remotely looks like it might contain a number.